# Saving single field to two (or multiple) tables - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three models - `Books`, `Authors` and `BookAuthors`. `Books` and `Authors` are in many-to-many 
relationship, through `BookAuthors`.

I want to create a form for entering books into database, but there lies my problem. I'd like for the `Author` field there to do two things:

> 1. If there is no author with entered name in Authors table, save it there.
> 2. Regardless of what happens in 1), it should create an entry in BookAuthors, with book_id, author_id (wether it's freshly created, or
>      found an existing one in Authors table), and author_type_id.

I don't know how to make *one* field refer to multiple tables.

Comment: So you're saying you want to reference an author regardless of whether a record exists in the database already? If no author record exists, save it, else use one that's already there?

Comment: @RichPeck I'm saying I want to search the `authors` table for the name entered in the form. Then, if it already exists, take its ID and store it in `book_authors` table, along with corresponding `book_id`. If it **doesn't** exist, I want to create a new entry in `authors` table, THEN take its ID, and store in in `book_authors` along with `book_id`.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
#app/controllers/books_controller.rb
def new
    @book = Book.new
    @authors = Author.all
end

def create
    @book = Book.new(book_params)
    @book.save
end

private

def book_params
    require(:book).permit(:name, author_id: [], authors_attributes: [:name])
end


#app/views/books/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @book do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Name" %>
    <%= f.collection_select :author_id, Author.all, :id, :name, prompt: "Pick an Author"> %>
    <%= f.fields_for :authors do |author| %> 
        <%= author.text_field :name, placeholder: "New Author Name" %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

---

**Process**

This basically gives you a way to select a pre-defined author OR create a new one

If a new one is created, the system will save & reference the new author, whilst an existing author will just show the `id` of the existing author

Comment: I should have mentioned in the question that BookAuthors is a join model, and has `author_id` and `book_id`, along with some other columns - simply because a book can have multiple authors. So if a book already has authors, they are stored in `book_authors`, and the view should select their IDs from `book_authors` and then find their names in `authors`.